# creating an exchange platform based on ethereum smart contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens

I am trying to build a platform ( similar to a wallet website ) that allows authenticated users to trade currency between them. this currency is not a real currency so it can be just a regular `erc20` token.

my question is regarding the implementation of this idea, would it be better to start on my own ( from scratch ) or use something like the `0xProtocol`. ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used 0x protocol and it is amazing. I will highly recommend it.

You can build custom off-chain relayers , which will relay transactions from maker to creator.

0x has concise and helpful documentation with a starter project to setup and run immidiately .

Alternatively, you can look at KyberNetwork also. They do the same thing but they are not a protocol , just an exchange with Open apis. Though 0x support more (almost any) ERC20 tokens).

Alternatively, you can build custom contracts leveraging approve and transferFrom functions of any ERC20 contract.

Note: All three are for only ERC20 tokens on Ethereum

Comment: so how can I exactly use the 0xProtocol in the idea of exchange I want to make.

Comment: Begin here: https://0xproject.com/wiki

Comment: 0x will provide you a base to exchange tokens (protocol). You can build on top of it.